# How can i compile this assembly code written with nasm on 64 bit?

Tags: assembly, nasm

Can I run this on 64 bit?

```
 ;
 ; assemble and link with:
 ; nasm -f elf printf-test.asm && gcc -m32 -o printf-test printf-test.o
 ;
 section .text
 global main
 extern printf

 main:

  mov eax, 0xDEADBEEF
  push eax
  push message
  call printf
  add esp, 8
  ret

  message db "Register = %08X", 10, 0
```

I got this error

```
~/Desktop$ nasm -f elf printTest.asm
~/Desktop$ gcc -m32 -o printTest printTest.o
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../libc.so when searching for -lc
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../libc.a when searching for -lc
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so when searching for -lc
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a when searching for -lc
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: rewrite it to match the assembler of a 64bit CPU

Comment: Have you tried running it?

Comment: What's the question? If you have some trouble running it, then just write it here.

Comment: Yes, I tried running it and I got this error in my edited question.

Comment: Looks like you don't have `multilib` installed. The GCC needs x86 libs to compile for 32bit arch

Comment: Can you tell me how I can install it?

Comment: You didn't specify your OS.

Comment: It depends on your distributive. Just open the packet manager or software manager or whatever you have and search for multilib. Then install it. Can't say much more without knowing your distro.

Comment: I am using Naty Narwhal 11.04.

Comment: In Debian-based distros you can do `apt-get install gcc-multilib` (with root privileges). You can always use `apt-cache search multilib` to see what's the exact package name.

Comment: I love you, guys. Thank you, it worked. =)